# Transformation of discrete random variables, given support

Tags: data-transformation, random-variable, discrete-data

Suppose that we have a discrete random variable X with support `S={1,2,3}`, with probabilities of, respectively, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5. How could I find the PDF of Y if Y = (X+10)^2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill in the missing entries in this table:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
X &\quad Y\\
1 &\quad (1+10)^2\\
2 &\quad ?\\
3 &\quad ?\\
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Now, $\Pr(X=1)=0.1$, so $\Pr(Y=(1+10)^2)=\dots$?